# Android Studio Application does not starts from the main menu and crashes on the click of a button

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

I'm a beginner in android, I'm trying to make a quiz game. Although the application is running in my mobile but with few problems. (using real device)

1st Problem - First time the app runs fine, after the game is complete, if you press the back button, it navigates to main menu. After that if you click the start button, the app crashes (unfortunately, appname has stopped.)

2nd Problem - After quitting the game, if i launch the application again, it starts from the quiz rather than the main menu.

How can i fix them?

**Here is the logcat error report**

```
    09-17 15:33:57.333  11833-11833/com.example.ice.quizgametest E/ViewRootImpl﹕ onInputEvent:dispatchAttachedToWindow is not called.[event:KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=158, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=47573455, downTime=47573407, deviceId=2, displayId=0, source=0x101 }]
    09-17 15:33:58.384  11833-11833/com.example.ice.quizgametest E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
    09-17 15:34:11.046  11833-11833/com.example.ice.quizgametest E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
    09-17 15:34:12.988  11833-11833/com.example.ice.quizgametest D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    09-17 15:34:12.988  11833-11833/com.example.ice.quizgametest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ed7930)
    09-17 15:34:12.988  11833-11833/com.example.ice.quizgametest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ice.quizgametest/com.example.ice.quizgametest.quiz}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
                at com.example.ice.quizgametest.quiz.onCreate(quiz.java:45)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your question shows that you are not familiar in the life cycle of an android application. You should study the theory a little better.

Comment: Please can you post the logcat error report when the application crashes along with portion of code...rather giving us complete project

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1

Exception which you paste there tells you everything. First of all when you analyzing exception in most common situations u have to find "Caused by" part of your exception. 
This line:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2

It tells you that you try to get or set element from outside of size of your Array. Probably you start indexing from 1 instead of 0 or any other cause.
Line under:

> at com.example.ice.quizgametest.quiz.onCreate(quiz.java:45)

gives you full path where exception occurs. Its class: quiz, method: onCreate, line: 45. Just debug this situation and try find your solution.

### Question 2

You have to read about Activity [LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.    tv.setText(questions[position]); This is line 45 in quiz class. Might be it is trying to find the position 2 which is not in the array. How can i fix it?

Comment: @msa Probrably your static varriable position is never set to default value. You have to read about static variables and Garbage Collector. Probably if  you create onDestroy event in this activity and set there your position variable to 0 everything will be fine.